# When does patent US 5891453 A expire?

Tags: us5891453

When does patent [US 5891453 A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5891453A/en) expire? Also, does it fully encompass the entire suite of Crest Whitestrips line of products, or were individual patents filed for each "strength" of their Crest Whitestrip line (regular vs advanced whitening)?

Answer (score 1):

The document [US5891453A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5891453A) has **expired** on **6th of June 2017** (i.e. 20 years from the priority date). To answer the second part of your question I had to assess the claims of the document and its family members.

The document belongs to family of **79 patents**. [Click for Espacenet family link](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=US&NR=5879691A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=&date=19990309&DB=&locale=)

I did a quick read through of the publications with distinct names and it appears that the claims usually consist of various combinations of a delivery system, teeth whitening strips, teeth whitening gel, shapes of teeth whitening strips and a toothbrush. There is no mention about the "*strength*" of its product line.

I am led to believe that this is the entire range of Crest whitestrips productline that is in existence now([Crest whitestrips](https://www.pgshop.com/pgshop-hers-oral-whiten/)). It appears that around 2010 the productline saw major changes as most of the previous products were discontinued ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_Whitestrips)) And around the same time another family of patents are noted to be filed. [CA2888199A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/CA2888199A1) is a representative of that family. It seems that this family of patents are an improvement over the previous family and this family of patents discloses information on similar products in the market (for eg. CREST 3D WHITE WHITESTRIPS ADVANCED SEAL PROFESSIONAL EFFECT). As I'm not entirely sure about what you mean by *strength* of their Crest Whitestrip line, I suggest you read through the publications of this family as well([Espacenet link to this family](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=CA&NR=2888199A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20140424&DB=&locale=)).

So to sum up, the document [US5891453A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5891453A) and its family members to my best knowledge have broad claims and they **do not disclose** information regarding the *strength* of their Crest Whitestrip line.

Hope this helped. Always open to constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first question easily enough. The patent term is 20 years from the priority date of June 6th, 1997. Thus it should expire on June 6th, 2017. To answer the other questions would require searching of other patents from Procter and Gamble to see if there are others in the family.